# HQL Result is incorrect

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hql

I have this hql query in list method:

```
public List<Alumno> list(Map<String, String> queryParams) {

        String hql = "from Alumno as a "
                + "WHERE a.nombre LIKE CONCAT('%', :nombre)";

        Query query = sessionFactory
                .getCurrentSession()
                .createQuery(hql);

        query.setParameter("nombre", queryParams.get("nombre"));

        List<Alumno> lista = query.list();
        return lista;
    }
```

When I use `nombre` with the value `a` it works correctly, but with other values ​​it doesn't.

Is the query well done?

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting an error with this code or is it just not returning any value?

If it's the first case, please post the error so we can help a bit more :)

If it is the second, check what value you're getting from `queryParams.get("nombre")`. The problem may be that the value you're passing to your `query.setParameter()` doesn't match anything in your DB, hence nothing is returned.